# Building alpine based images for PowerPC (PPC64le) fails when trying to run apk add

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, powerpc

Adding any apk packages whilst building docker images for target platform linux/ppc64le results in a "bad signature" error.

```
    6 0.470 (1/1) Installing sudo (1.8.27-r0) 6 0.537 ERROR: sudo-1.8.27-r0: BAD signature
```

I have tried many packages and all of them results in this error. I have however been successful if I use alpine version 3.8 and below.

Im doing a docker build using buildx on my Macbook Pro (X86) I can successfully build docker images for operating systems ubuntu and debian from my macbook for PPC64le, but not for alpine version 3.9 and above.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk add sudo
```

#### Docker build command

```
docker buildx build -t alpine_test  . --platform=linux/ppc64le --load
```

I expect this simple build script to build a simple alpine docker image for linux/ppc64le architecture with the sudo package installed.
However I get the following error during the build process:

```
[+] Building 3.6s (6/6) FINISHED => [internal] load build 
definition from Dockerfile 0.0s => => transferring dockerfile: 81B 0.0s => [internal] load .dockerignore 0.0s => => transferring context: 2B 0.0s => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest 2.9s => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:72c42ed48c3a2db31b7dafe17d275b634664a708d901ec9fd57b1529280f01fb 0.0s => => resolve docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:72c42ed48c3a2db31b7dafe17d275b634664a708d901ec9fd57b1529280f01fb 0.0s => CACHED [2/3] RUN apk update 0.0s
=> ERROR [3/3] RUN apk add sudo 0.7s
[3/3] RUN apk add sudo:
6 0.452 (1/1) Installing sudo (1.8.27-r0)
6 0.566 ERROR: sudo-1.8.27-r0: BAD signature
#6 0.577 1 error; 6 MiB in 14 packages
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add sudo]: exit code: 1
```